# How to get the number of values from a drop down menu when there is only one default value in the DOM?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Ok straightforward but there is a snag.  I am trying to get the number of values from a drop down menu.  The drop down menu always has a default which is reflected in the DOM.  As you can see in the html there is only one.  Firstly what xpath should I use driver.FindElement(By.XPATH("//div[@class='Select-value']") but this wouldn't work right?  Please help me write the code to get the values from the drop down.  Thanks oh and just to be clear the default value is Fleet1015075755737

```
 Select-value
```

Here is the default value in the DOM:

```
<div class="Select-value"><span class="Select-value-label" role="option" aria-selected="true" id="react-select-4--value-item">Fleet1015075755737</span></div>
```

[image]

The full DOM is below as you can see or search there is only one value in the drop down per DOM:

```
 href="/AppDist/admin~forgottenPassword~organisationSettings~reporting.15a8d19 
 de 
 22dbc226491.css"><script charset="utf-8" 
 src="/AppDist/ch.admin~forgottenPassword~organisationSettings~reporting.b6fd0 
 b3 
 6cbaeebb99372.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
 href="/AppDist/admin~organisationSettings~reporting.dc3718bb2d54323645e4.css"     
  <script charset="utf-8" 
 src="/AppDist/ch.admin~organisationSettings~reporting.7258270708935c516c1c.js"> 
 </script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
  href="/AppDist/admin.03f8b4765436ef6bd5e9.css"><script charset="utf-8" 
  src="/AppDist/ch.admin.dc2e985c46d2bf065d87.js"></script><style 
  type="text/css"></style><style type="text/css"></style><style
  type="text/css"> 
 </style><style type="text/css"></style><style type="text/css"></style><style 
  type="text/css"></style><style type="text/css"></style><style 
  type="text/css"> 
 </style><style type="text/css"></style><style type="text/css"></style><style 
  type="text/css"></style><style type="text/css"></style><style 
  type="text/css"> 
 </style><style type="text/css"></style><style type="text/css"></style><style 
  type="text/css"></style><style type="text/css"></style><style 
  type="text/css"> 
 </style><style type="text/css"></style><style type="text/css"></style><style 
  type="text/css"></style><style type="text/css"></style><style 
  type="text/css"> 
 </style><style type="text/css"></style><style type="text/css"></style><style 
  type="text/css"></style><style type="text/css"></style><style 
  type="text/css"> 
 </style><style type="text/css"></style><style type="text/css"></style><style 
  type="text/css"></style><style type="text/css"></style><style 
  type="text/css"> 
 </style><style type="text/css"></style><style type="text/css"></style><style 
  type="text/css"></style><style type="text/css"></style><style 
  type="text/css"> 
 </style><style type="text/css"></style><style type="text/css"></style><style 
  type="text/css"></style><style type="text/css"></style><style 
  type="text/css"> 
 </style><style type="text/css"></style><style type="text/css"></style><style 
  type="text/css"></style><style type="text/css"></style><style 
  type="text/css"> 
 </style><style type="text/css"></style><style type="text/css"></style><style 
  type="text/css"></style><style type="text/css"></style></head>
  <symbol xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="icons_geofence" viewBox="0 0 
  <div id="app"><div class="vt-app-container"><main id="rootContainer"><div 
  class="vt-modal-wrapper"></div><div class="vt-navbar"><div class="vt- 
  navbar__brand"><a class="vt-navbar__brand-link active" aria-current="page" 
  href="/"><span class="vt-navbar__impersonating">Impersonating M-Powered 
  Automation</span><svg class="icon icon--logo-a vt-navbar__brand-logo--a" 
  width="40" height="26"><use xlink:href="#icons_logo-a"></use></svg><svg 
  class="icon icon--logo vt-navbar__brand-logo--full" width="250" height="26"> 
  <use xlink:href="#icons_logo"></use></svg></a></div><nav class="vt- 
   navbar__nav"><ul class="vt-navbar__menu"><li class="vt-navbar__menu-item"> 
  <a 
  class="vt-navbar__menu-item-link" title="Tracking" href="/tracking"><svg 
  class="icon icon--tracking vt-navbar__menu-item-icon" width="24" 
  height="22"> 
  <use xlink:href="#icons_tracking"></use></svg><span class="vt-navbar__menu- 
  item-label">Tracking</span></a></li><li class="vt-navbar__menu-item"><a 
  class="vt-navbar__menu-item-link" title="Dash" href="/dashboard"><svg 
  class="icon icon--dash vt-navbar__menu-item-icon" width="24" height="22"> 
 <use 
  xlink:href="#icons_dash"></use></svg><span class="vt-navbar__menu-item- 
 label">Dash</span></a></li><li class="vt-navbar__menu-item"><a class="vt- 
 navbar__menu-item-link" title="Media" href="/media"><svg class="icon icon-- 
 video vt-navbar__menu-item-icon" width="24" height="22"><use 
  xlink:href="#icons_video"></use></svg><span class="vt-navbar__menu-item- 
 label">Media</span></a></li><li class="vt-navbar__menu-item vt-navbar__menu- 
 item--mobile-hidden"><a class="vt-navbar__menu-item-link" title="Reporting" 
  href="/reporting/vehicles"><svg class="icon icon--bar-chart vt-navbar__menu- 
 item-icon" width="24" height="22"><use xlink:href="#icons_bar-chart"></use> 
 </svg><span class="vt-navbar__menu-item-label">Reporting</span></a></li><li 
  class="vt-navbar__menu-item vt-navbar__menu-item--has-children vt- 
 navbar__menu-item--mobile-hidden"><a class="vt-navbar__menu-item-link" 
  title="System" href="/admin/vehicles"><svg class="icon icon--system vt- 
 navbar__menu-item-icon" width="24" height="22"><use 
  xlink:href="#icons_system"></use></svg><span class="vt-navbar__menu-item- 
  label">System</span></a><div class="vt-navbar__child-menu"><ul class="vt- 
  navbar__child-menu-list"><li class="vt-navbar__child-menu-item vt- 
  navbar__menu-item--mobile-hidden"><a class="vt-navbar__child-menu-link" 
  title="Audit History" href="/admin/audit">Audit History</a></li><li 
  class="vt-navbar__child-menu-item vt-navbar__menu-item--mobile-hidden"><a 
  class="vt-navbar__child-menu-link" title="Health Check" 
  href="/admin/healthcheck">Health Check</a></li><li class="vt-navbar__child- 
 menu-item vt-navbar__menu-item--mobile-hidden"><a class="vt-navbar__child- 
 menu-link" title="Platform Management" 
  href="/admin/platform/devices">Platform Management</a></li><li class="vt- 
 navbar__child-menu-item vt-navbar__menu-item--mobile-hidden"><a class="vt- 
  navbar__child-menu-link active" title="Vehicle Management" 
  href="/admin/vehicles" aria-current="page">Vehicle Management</a></li><li 
  class="vt-navbar__child-menu-item vt-navbar__menu-item--mobile-hidden"><a 
  class="vt-navbar__child-menu-link" title="Fleet Management" 
  href="/admin/fleets">Fleet Management</a></li><li class="vt-navbar__child- 
 menu-item vt-navbar__menu-item--mobile-hidden"><a class="vt-navbar__child- 
 menu-link" title="User Management" href="/admin/users">User Management</a> 
 </li></ul></div></li><li class="vt-navbar__menu-item vt-navbar__menu-item-- 
 has-children"><a class="vt-navbar__menu-item-link" title="User" 
  href="/admin/vehicles"><svg class="icon icon--driver vt-navbar__menu-item- 
  icon" width="24" height="22"><use xlink:href="#icons_driver"></use></svg> 
 <span class="vt-navbar__menu-item-label">User</span></a><div class="vt- 
 navbar__child-menu"><ul class="vt-navbar__child-menu-list"><li class="vt- 
 navbar__child-menu-item vt-navbar__menu-item--mobile-hidden"><a class="vt- 
 navbar__child-menu-link" title="Organisation" 
  href="/organisation">Organisation</a></li><li class="vt-navbar__child-menu- 
 item"><a class="vt-navbar__child-menu-link" title="Profile" 
  href="/profile">Profile</a></li><li class="vt-navbar__child-menu-item"><span 
  class="vt-navbar__child-menu-link" title="Logout" role="button" 
  tabindex="0">Logout</span></li><li class="vt-navbar__child-menu-item vt- 
 navbar__menu-item--mobile-hidden"><a class="vt-navbar__child-menu-link" 
  href="/admin/vehicles"><div class="vt-navbar__impersonate"><div class="vt- 
 form-select vt-navbar__impersonate-select"><div class="Select has-value is- 
 clearable is-searchable Select--single"><input name="entity" type="hidden" 
  value="0f9c97c6-2dc5-4aa0-8b4e-824c6419b321"><div class="Select-control"> 
  <span class="Select-multi-value-wrapper" id="react-select-3--value"><div 
  class="Select-value"><span class="Select-value-label" role="option" aria- 
 selected="true" id="react-select-3--value-item">M-Powered Automation</span> 
 </div><div class="Select-input" style="display: inline-block;"><input     
  autocomplete="" aria-activedescendant="react-select-3--value" aria- 
 expanded="false" aria-haspopup="false" aria-owns="" role="combobox" value="" 
  style="box-sizing: content-box; width: 5px;"><div style="position: absolute; 
  top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; overflow: scroll; white- 
 space: pre; font-size: 11.522px; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Helvetica, 
  Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; letter-spacing: 
  normal; text-transform: none;"></div></div></span><span aria-label="Clear 
  value" class="Select-clear-zone" title="Clear value"><span class="Select- 
  clear">?</span></span><span class="Select-arrow-zone"><span class="Select- 
  arrow"></span></span></div></div></div></div></a></li></ul></div></li></ul> 
  </nav><div class="vt-navbar__alerts"><button type="button" class="vt-btn vt- 
  btn--notification"><svg class="icon icon--media-requests" width="22" 
  height="20"><use xlink:href="#icons_media-requests"></use></svg></button> 
  <button type="button" class="vt-btn vt-btn--notification"><div class="vt- 
  navbar__alerts-count"><span>0</span></div><svg class="icon icon--events" 
  width="20" height="18"><use xlink:href="#icons_events"></use></svg></button> 
 </div></div><div class="vt-content-container"><div style="width: inherit;"><div 
  class="vt-transition-panel vt-transition-panel--left vt-transition-panel-- 
 small" style="transform: none;"><div class="vt-panel vt-devices-and-drivers"> 
  <div class="vt-panel-header"><div class="vt-panel-header__title"><h1 
  class="vt-panel-header__heading">Devices and Drivers</h1></div><div class="vt- 
 panel-header__tabs"><ul class="vt-panel-header__tabs-menu"><li class="vt-panel- 
 header__tabs-menu-item vt-panel-header__tabs--active"><button type="button" 
  class="vt-btn vt-btn--link"><svg class="icon icon--device icon--left" 
  width="18" height="18"><use xlink:href="#icons_device"></use></svg><span 
  class="vt-panel-header__tabs-menu-label">Devices</span></button></li><li 
  class="vt-panel-header__tabs-menu-item"><button type="button" class="vt-btn 
  vt-btn--link"><svg class="icon icon--driver icon--left" width="18" 
  height="18"><use xlink:href="#icons_driver"></use></svg><span class="vt-panel- 
 header__tabs-menu-label">Drivers</span></button></li></ul></div><div class="vt- 
 panel-header__content"><div class="vt-devices-and-drivers__actions"><div 
  class="vt-form-input"><label for="driver-search" class="vt-label vt-form- 
 input__label"><span>Filter Results</span></label><input class="vt-input vt- 
 form-field" autocomplete="" id="driver-search" placeholder="Filter Results..." 
  type="text" value=""><div class="vt-validation-container"></div></div></div> 
 </div></div><div class="vt-panel vt-device-list-panel"><div class="vt-devices- 
 list"><div style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 
  100%;"><div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; 
  bottom: 0px; overflow: scroll; margin-right: -17px; margin-bottom: -17px;"> 
 <div class="vt-client-paged-list"><div class="vt-client-paged-list__data-page"> 
 <div class="vt-client-paged-list__empty">Nothing to display.</div></div></div> 
 </div><div style="position: absolute; height: 6px; right: 2px; bottom: 2px; 
  left: 2px; border-radius: 3px;"><div style="position: relative; display: 
  block; height: 100%; cursor: pointer; border-radius: inherit; background- 
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); width: 0px;"></div></div><div style="position: 
  absolute; width: 6px; right: 2px; bottom: 2px; top: 2px; border-radius: 3px;"> 
 <div style="position: relative; display: block; width: 100%; cursor: pointer; 
  border-radius: inherit; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); height: 0px; 
  transform: translateY(0px);"></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div> 
 <div class="vt-page vt-page--left-panel-open vt-page--left-panel-small vt-page- 
 -right-panel-small"><div style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 
 100%; height: 100%;"><div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; 
  right: 0px; bottom: 0px; overflow: scroll; margin-right: -17px; margin-bottom: 
  -17px;"><div class="vt-vehicle-management"><div class="vt-page-header"><div 
  class="vt-page-header__title"><h1 class="vt-page-header__title- 
 heading">Vehicle Management</h1><div class="vt-page-header__title-content"> 
 </div></div><div class="vt-page-header__content"></div></div><div class="vt- 
 page__body"><div class="vt-vehicle-management__actions"><div class="vt-form- 
 select"><div class="Select has-value is-searchable Select--single"><div 
  class="Select-control"><span class="Select-multi-value-wrapper" id="react- 
  select-4--value"><div class="Select-value"><span class="Select-value-label" 
  role="option" aria-selected="true" id="react-select-4--value- 
 item">Fleet1015075755737</span></div><div class="Select-input" style="display: 
  inline-block;"><input autocomplete="" aria-activedescendant="react-select-4-- 
 value" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="false" aria-owns="" role="combobox" 
  value="" style="box-sizing: content-box; width: 5px;"><div style="position: 
  absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; overflow: 
  scroll; white-space: pre; font-size: 11.522px; font-family: &quot;Open 
  Sans&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-style: 
  normal; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none;"></div></div></span> 
  <span class="Select-arrow-zone"><span class="Select-arrow"></span></span> 
  </div></div></div><button type="button" title="Manage Tags" class="vt-btn vt- 
  vehicle-management__add" disabled="">Manage Tags<svg class="icon icon--tags 
  icon--right" width="16" height="16"><use xlink:href="#icons_tags"></use></svg> 
  </button><button type="button" title="Add User" class="vt-btn vt-vehicle- 
  management__add">Add New Vehicle<svg class="icon icon--car icon--right" 
  width="16" height="16"><use xlink:href="#icons_car"></use></svg></button> 
  </div><div class="vt-list-view-filters"><div class="vt-list-view- 
  filters__content"><button type="button" class="vt-btn vt-btn--link vt-list- 
 view-filters__toggle"><svg class="icon icon--filter icon--left" width="14" 
  height="14"><use xlink:href="#icons_filter"></use></svg>Filters</button></div> 
 <div class="vt-list-view-filters__filters" style="height: 0px; overflow: 
  hidden;"><div class="vt-vehicle-management__filters"><div class="vt-form-input 
  vt-form-field"><label class="vt-label vt-form-input__label"><span>VRN</span> 
 </label><input class="vt-input" autocomplete="" name="registration" 
  placeholder="VRN" value=""><div class="vt-validation-container"></div></div> 
 <div class="vt-form-select vt-form-field"><label for="" class="vt-label vt- 
 form-input__label">Vehicle Type</label><div class="Select is-clearable is- 
 searchable Select--single"><div class="Select-control"><span class="Select- 
 multi-value-wrapper" id="react-select-5--value"><div class="Select- 
 placeholder">Select a vehicle type...</div><div class="Select-input" 
  style="display: inline-block;"><input autocomplete="" aria- 
 activedescendant="react-select-5--value" aria-expanded="false" aria- 
 haspopup="false" aria-owns="" role="combobox" value="" style="box-sizing: 
  content-box; width: 5px;"><div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; 
  visibility: hidden; height: 0px; overflow: scroll; white-space: pre; font- 
 size: 11.522px; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans- 
 serif; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; letter-spacing: normal; text- 
 transform: none;"></div></div></span><span class="Select-arrow-zone"><span 
  class="Select-arrow"></span></span></div></div></div><div class="vt-form-input 
  vt-form-field"><label class="vt-label vt-form-input__label"><span>Vehicle 
  Make</span></label><input class="vt-input" autocomplete="" name="make" 
  placeholder="Make..." value=""><div class="vt-validation-container"></div> 
 </div><div class="vt-form-input vt-form-field"><label class="vt-label vt-form- 
 input__label"><span>Vehicle Model</span></label><input class="vt-input" 
  autocomplete="" name="model" placeholder="Model..." value=""><div class="vt- 
 validation-container"></div></div><div class="vt-form-input vt-form-field"> 
 <label class="vt-label vt-form-input__label"><span>Fuel Type</span></label> 
 <input class="vt-input" autocomplete="" name="fuelType" placeholder="Fuel 
  type..." value=""><div class="vt-validation-container"></div></div><div 
  class="vt-form-input vt-form-field"><label class="vt-label vt-form- 
 input__label"><span>Engine Size</span></label><input class="vt-input" 
  autocomplete="" name="engineSize" placeholder="Engine Size..." value=""><div 
  class="vt-validation-container"></div></div><div class="vt-form-input vt-form- 
 field"><label class="vt-label vt-form-input__label"><span>Device Id</span> 
 </label><input class="vt-input" autocomplete="" name="deviceId" 
  placeholder="Device Id..." value=""><div class="vt-validation-container"> 
  </div></div><div class="vt-vehicle-management__filters-submit"><button 
  type="button" class="vt-btn vt-btn--block">Search</button></div></div></div> 
  </div><div class="vt-with-checkboxes"><div class="vt-paged-list"><div 
   class="vt-paged-list__header"><div role="presentation" class="vt-list-view- 
  cell vt-list-view-cell__header vt-list-view-cell__checkbox"><div><span 
  class="vt-with-checkboxes__title">Select</span><div class="vt-checkbox vt- 
  with-checkboxes__checkbox"><input class="vt-checkbox__input" type="checkbox"> 
  <div class="" style="display: inline;"><svg class="vt-checkbox__svg" 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 18 18"><rect class="vt- 
 checkbox__box" x="1" y="1" width="16" height="16" rx="2"></rect><path 
  class="vt-checkbox__tick" x="0" y="-2" d="M13.279,8.27,8.123,13.382a.433.433,0,0,1-.612,0l-2.979-3a.433.433,0,0,1,0-.612L5.559,8.751a.433.433,0,0,1,.612,0l1.658,1.671,3.824-3.791a.433.433,0,0,1,.612,0l1.016,1.024a.433.433,0,0,1,0,.612Z" style="display: none;"></path><path class="vt-checkbox__question" d="M6,11a1,1,0,1,1,1-1A1,1,0,0,1,6,11Zm.833-3.54v.045a.5.5,0,0,1-.5.495h-.51a.5.5,0,0,1-.495-.495V7a.753.753,0,0,1,.417-.672C6.707,5.85,7.333,5.5,7.333,5a1.224,1.224,0,0,0-1.25-1.25,1.252,1.252,0,0,0-1.194.879A.508.508,0,0,1,4.411,5H3.884A.5.5,0,0,1,3.4,4.389,2.754,2.754,0,0,1,6. 
 083,2.25,2.724,2.724,0,0,1,8.833,5c0,1.28-1.023,1.952-2,2.46Z" 
  transform="translate(3 2.5)" style="display: none;"></path><path class="vt- 
 checkbox__error" 
  d="M14.985,16.178a1.68,1.68,0,1,0,1.68,1.68A1.68,1.68,0,0,0,14.985,16.178Zm- 
 1.6- 
 6.04.271,4.968a.438.438,0,0,0,.438.414h1.773a.438.438,0,0,0,.438-.414l.271- 
 4.968a.438.438,0,0,0-.438-.462H13.827A.438.438,0,0,0,13.389,10.138Z" 
  transform="translate(-6 -6.25)" style="display: none;"></path></svg></div> 
 </div> 
 </div></div><div role="presentation" class="vt-list-view-cell vt-list-view- 
 cell__header"><div>VRN</div></div><div role="presentation" class="vt-list-view- 
 cell vt-list-view-cell__header"><div>Make</div></div><div role="presentation" 
  class="vt-list-view-cell vt-list-view-cell__header"><div>Model</div></div><div 
  role="presentation" class="vt-list-view-cell vt-list-view-cell__header"> 
 <div>Driver Name</div></div><div role="presentation" class="vt-list-view-cell 
  vt-list-view-cell__header vt-vehicle-list-view__actions"><div>Action</div> 
 </div> 
 </div><div class="vt-paged- 
  list__content"><div><div style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 
  100%; height: auto; min-height: 0px; max-height: 500px;"><div 
  style="position: 
  relative; overflow: scroll; margin-right: -17px; margin-bottom: -17px; min- 
  height: 17px; max-height: 517px;"><div class="vt-paged-list__empty"><div 
  class="vt-empty-state"><svg class="icon icon--question vt-empty-state__icon" 
  width="100" height="100"><use xlink:href="#icons_question"></use></svg><span 
  class="vt-empty-state__title">No Data Found.</span><p class="vt-empty- 
 state__message"></p></div></div></div><div style="position: absolute; height: 
  6px; right: 2px; bottom: 2px; left: 2px; border-radius: 3px;"><div 
  style="position: relative; display: block; height: 100%; cursor: pointer; 
  border-radius: inherit; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); width: 0px; 
  transform: translateX(0px);"></div></div><div style="position: absolute; 
  width: 6px; right: 2px; bottom: 2px; top: 2px; border-radius: 3px;"><div 
  style="position: relative; display: block; width: 100%; cursor: pointer; 
  border-radius: inherit; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); height: 0px;"> 
 </div></div></div><div class="shadow-scrollbars__top" style="opacity: 0;"> 
 </div><div class="shadow-scrollbars__bottom" style="opacity: 0;"></div></div> 
 </div><div class="vt-paged-list__page-controls"><button type="button" 
  class="vt-btn vt-btn--passive" disabled=""><svg class="icon icon--arrow-left 
  icon--left" width="16" height="16"><use xlink:href="#icons_arrow-left"> 
 </use> 
 </svg>Previous</button><button type="button" class="vt-btn vt-btn--passive" 
  disabled="">Next<svg class="icon icon--arrow-right icon--right" width="16" 
  height="16"><use xlink:href="#icons_arrow-right"></use></svg></button></div> 
 </div></div></div></div></div><div style="position: absolute; height: 6px; 
  right: 2px; bottom: 2px; left: 2px; border-radius: 3px;"><div 
  style="position: 
  relative; display: block; height: 100%; cursor: pointer; border-radius: 
  inherit; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); width: 0px; transform: 
  translateX(0px);"></div></div><div style="position: absolute; width: 6px; 
  right: 2px; bottom: 2px; 
  top: 2px; border-radius: 3px;"><div style="position: relative; display: 
  block; 
  width: 100%; cursor: pointer; border-radius: inherit; background-color: 
  rgba(0, 
  0, 0, 0.2); height: 0px; transform: translateY(0px);"></div></div></div> 
 </div> 
   </div></main><div></div></div></div>
  <div id="titlestuff"></div>
  <div id="optionsstuff"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs- 
   core.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs- 
   ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs- 
   service.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs- 
   mapevents.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs- 
   clustering.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
    src="https://js.datalens.api.here.com/latest/mapsjs-datalens.js"></script>

    <!-- misc ui controls -->
    <!-- script type="text/javascript" 
    src="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-pano.js"></script -->
    <script type="text/javascript" 
  src="/AppDist/entry.54945656b9bf00912727.js"> 
   </script><script type="text/javascript" 
  src="/AppDist/ch.vendors~entry.4b1f8facdf1e7ffd95ed.js"></script>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get all the elements:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("Select-value-label"))
```

You could also use the role="option" attribute: `driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("role='option'"))`

Further, you can get the size, iterate trough list or what else you want to do.

Comment: Why do I only get a count of 2?  There are about 108 values?

Comment: Click on the default element, inspect the area and show us some of the elements in the DOM, maybe they have other properties that the default one

Comment: There could be a problem with a dropdawn being hidden. Try clicking first.